# Issue with loading 200+ list box items in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I am crating updated Gowalla application for windows phone mango. In that, in a particular area i need to populate around more than 1000 list items in a list. The minimum item count need to populate is 200. So i tried the ordinary implementation(list populating as a response of RX web request response ). Here the count of memory is mounting like Everest.  How i can implement the same effectively. Will lazy loading would be a solution for this. If yes is the answer how i can implement this lazy loading in windows phone mango..

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6170640/lazy-loading-of-listbox-images-from-isolated-storage

Comment: Its a pretty old one; plays with wp7 and not apt for my implementation. I tried the same in my app and badly failed 

Comment: How are you adding the items? Are you using a the ItemsSource property binded to some collection? What collection type are you using (ObservableCollection or other type)? Some code would be nice...

Comment: I must be missing something, 1000 doesn't seem like a lot.

Comment: Yup.. i am using Observable Collection for holding the data. But the issue is that, i am parsing a webpage for fetching the data with the help of Rx request and Regular expression. Ie each time the OnNext() of Rx executes i will get the desired object and i will add that object to observable collection. So in this scenario how i can apply the data virtulization. More over inside my first request i am sending 2 more request for fetching data from other websites. 

Comment: @Derek 1000 could be huge for a phone, especially if there's anything other than a single string in the display of each item, it could easily be an issue on performance and memory.

Answer (score 2):

I think you really need to reconsider the design of the app, rather than tryign to solve this perf issue.

For a user to find an item by scrolling amongst 1000 others on a small screen is typically a very bad way of enabling the user to make the selection.
Other approaches which may be more suitable include: jump lists, paging, search, sub-dividing or grouping items.

The bottom line is that you're probably trying to solve the wrong problem in terms of creating the best app for the people actually using it.

Comment: Oh, listbox, it was late )  I was going to say, I load quite a bit of data in a jumplist and it handles it fine.