# Loading Images From Isolated Storage When requested

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have a 100 images stored in the Isolated Storage.And Now i want to  Bind them to ListBox when it requested.I can follow the Post [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6170640/lazy-loading-of-listbox-images-from-isolated-storage)

But i don't know how to implement.Because it doesn't interact with Isolated Storage.Please tell me or give me a solutionn.

Comment: If you have 100 images in Isolated Storage, where do you want to download them? Setting an imagesource  should do the job.

Comment: i mean bind them to listbox when needed

Comment: Can you show some code how you are trying to bind those images from Isolated Storage?

Answer (score 0):

[How to load an Image from IsolatedStorage and display it on Device (CSWP8ImageFromIsolatedStorage)](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/CSWP8ImageFromIsolatedStora-8dcf8411)